# Taskill vs. Tskill

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

I've seen both of these used to end processes. It is to my understanding that tskill is the older taskkill being that it's documentation is located in [Microsoft Windows's XP Documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ts_cmd_tskill.mspx?mfr=true) while the newer taskkill is capable of closing several programs at a time according to [Microsoft Technet Taskkill's Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx). What are the advantages or disadvantages of using either?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TSKILL really has no advantages, to my knowledge other than being what some people learned first.

Taskkill on the other hand does everything tskill does, but more, with better documentation and more flexibility. It also allows wildcards, easy remote killing `taskkill /s serverName /IM "firefox"' and allows you to control exit forcefulness (Force kill, or allow graceful exit).

Answer (score 0):

A noteworthy advantage of TSKILL is that it doesn't depend on the WMI service and can kill some privileged tasks that TASKKILL cannot

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).